# Link flapping when MTU is set by DHCP server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I'm facing a peculiar networking issue with an Ubuntu 18.04 system. One of my Ethernet interfaces exhibits link flapping only with one particular brand of router (Sierra Wireless MP70) and only when DHCP is enabled. I have exhaustively eliminated other factors. With a static IP set, the link functions fine and I see no other issues (e.g., no packet loss).

The observed behavior is that the link briefly comes online and appears to get a DHCP lease, immediately switches to `NO-CARRIER`, and then repeats.

I previously believed this to be a physical layer issue but I discovered that `NO-CARRIER` appears briefly after toggling the link from down to up, so my current hypothesis is that some system process is causing simply on a loop bringing the network up and down.

My netplan for this device is simply:

```
    eth1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-routes: false
```

Here is the part of the `systemd-networkd` log that loops:

```
eth1: Flags change: +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_34 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=12 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Gained carrier
eth1: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): STARTED on ifindex 4
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=13 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): DISCOVER
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): OFFER
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): REQUEST (requesting)
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): ACK
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): lease expires in 1d 23h 59min 59s
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): T2 expires in 1d 18h
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): T1 expires in 1d
eth1: DHCPv4 address 192.168.13.110/24 via 192.168.13.31
eth1: Setting MTU: 1430
Setting transient hostname: 'ifcb000'
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.hostname1 path=/org/freedesktop/hostname1 interface=org.freedesktop.hostname1 member=SetHostname cookie=14 reply_cookie=0 signature=sb error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Flags change: -LOWER_UP
eth1: Setting MTU done.
eth1: Updating address: 192.168.13.110/24 (valid for 2d)
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_34 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=15 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=16 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: DHCP error: could not get routes: No data available
Got message type=method_return sender=:1.6 destination=:1.2 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=3 reply_cookie=14 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Flags change: -RUNNING
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_34 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=17 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Lost carrier
DHCP CLIENT (0xe616919c): STOPPED
eth1: DHCP lease lost
eth1: Removing address 192.168.13.110
eth1: Setting MTU: 1500
Setting transient hostname: 'n/a'
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.hostname1 path=/org/freedesktop/hostname1 interface=org.freedesktop.hostname1 member=SetHostname cookie=18 reply_cookie=0 signature=sb error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Removing address 192.168.13.110
eth1: State is configuring, dropping config
Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=19 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Removing address: 192.168.13.110/24 (valid for 2d)
Got message type=method_return sender=:1.6 destination=:1.2 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4 reply_cookie=18 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
eth1: Setting MTU done.
eth1: Adding address: fe80::206:d5ff:fe2f:60c2/64 (valid forever)
eth1: Gained IPv6LL
eth1: Discovering IPv6 routers
NDISC: Started IPv6 Router Solicitation client
NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 4s
eth1: Flags change: +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
```

Comment: Could be related to this issue? https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9396 I confirmed Bionic's  `systemd` package does not have this patch applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further debugging, I determined this to be related to the DHCP Option 26 (Interface MTU) setting being passed by my DHCP server. Linux uses a default MTU of 1500, but the server sends an MTU of 1430.

I can either disable adhering to the DHCP-suggested MTU (`use-mtu: false`), or adjust the DHCP server's MTU setting to be 1500. This avoids the issue.

To confirm, I noted that the command `sudo ip link set dev eth1 mtu 1430` causes the link to go down and then come back up.